# Run meteor tests with Chimp at Codeship CI

Tags: bash, meteor, codeship

I have Meteor project and I want to run my tests with Chimp at Codeship.

I have a problem that Meteor project must be started before running Chimp. After starting Meteor, it blocks terminal showing that server si ready at localhost:3000

Usually at localhost I just run (and wait to start) Meteor. Then in another bash tab I run chimp.

At Codeship bash I cannot do such a thing. I tried some linux commands sleep, &, nohup but I cannot put it together.

#### Setup commands

```
# Install node
nvm install 4.0
nvm install 0.10
node -v

# Install chimp
npm install -g chimp

# Install meteor
curl -o meteor_install_script.sh https://install.meteor.com/
chmod +x meteor_install_script.sh
sed -i "s/type sudo >\/dev\/null 2>&1/\ false /g" meteor_install_script.sh
./meteor_install_script.sh
export PATH=$PATH:~/.meteor/
meteor --version
```

#### Test commands

```
nohup bash -c "meteor --settings=settingsRemote.json 2>&1 &" && sleep 3m; cat nohup.out
chimp --ddp=http://localhost:3000 --mocha --browser=firefox --path=tests
```

With above settings I got this output on meteor command. Chimp is never run.

```
[[[[[ ~/src/bitbucket.org/jirikrepl/nedatluj-meteor ]]]]]

=> Started proxy.
=> Started MongoDB.
=> Started your app.

=> App running at: http://localhost:3000/



------------------------------------------------------------------------------
This command didn't output anything for 10 minutes, thus we stopped it.
Please make sure your steps regularly print to standard out or standard error.
If the error is on our end please inform us so we can help you to fix this.
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok [here](https://documentation.codeship.com/continuous-integration/run-a-command-in-the-background/) is the solution. I edited code above, so it now works.

Comment: That link is broken @Jirik